# Changing project SDK when multiple SDK's

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea

I am trying to change the project SDK from `1.7.0_45` to `1.7.0_75` but when I try to select the SDK in project settings (IntelliJ IDEA) I am getting the message that:

`The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK`

I have set my `$PATH` and `&JAVA_HOME` and have ran out of ideas on how to fix it.

$PATH:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/colin/bin/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools:/home/colin/bin/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools`

$JAVA_HOME:

`/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45`

java -version:

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: i use eclipse, in eclipse threre is a menu to specify jdk paths for workspace. maybe case is similar with intellij. you should try to find it from menu then set jdk for project that newly added jdk

Comment: Which exactly directory are you selecting? Your PATH and JAVA_HOME make no difference when configuring a JDK in IntelliJ.

Comment: I'm trying to select `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75`

Comment: same problem here. No idea what to do....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with the rpm download. It seems to be at fault somehow. When I switched to the tar.gz version it worked fine.

Comment: Annoyingly this seemed to be the issue.